# DrRacket crash on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: racket, osx-yosemite

I'm using DrRacket on the newest version of OS X, Yosemite, but when I open DrRacket the systems tells me that "DrRacket quit unexpectedly". I've already tried restarting the computer, and I'm sure the I have the 64-bit version of Racket, so what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 21):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=14691) with Pango. Depending on whether you're using the 64-bit or 32-bit version of Racket, download the updated libraries:

- [64-bit](https://github.com/plt/libs/tree/master/draw-x86_64-macosx-2/racket/draw)
- [32-bit](https://github.com/plt/libs/tree/master/draw-i386-macosx-2/racket/draw)

You will need to grab all the libraries that contain `pango` in the name (`libpango`, `libpangocairo`, and `libpangoft2`) and overwrite the files in `/Applications/Racket v6.1/lib`.

Comment: Of course it did. ;-) I filed that bug report and have tested the fix on my own computer. :-)

Comment: I did this step but after that DrRacket didn't start at all.

Comment: @λhmadλjmi I had the same issue, then I download and replace all three pcks here (https://github.com/plt/libs/tree/master/draw-i386-macosx-2/racket/draw), tagged with "Mac OS X: incorporate Pango repair for Yosemite". Then it works again!

Comment: @fuiiii Surely, you should be using `draw-x86_64-macosx-2` instead of `draw-i386-macosx-2`, unless you downloaded the 32-bit Racket package instead of the 64-bit one.

Comment: where do you replace this? I looked everywhere in the folders and can't find anything with similar name

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young funny how I had the exact same question as choloboy just now ...

Comment: @SleeplessAnnoyedNerd: My original post had only the 64-bit library because 1. that's what the OP uses, and 2. I cannot believe anybody still uses the 32-bit version of Racket. Anyway, I've updated the post to accommodate both camps now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Version 6.1.1 which has been release on November 2014